# How to add extra parameters to a controller action without changing incoming model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Say I have a default model which is posted via AJAX:

```
var data = {
 // some members...

 newMember: true
}

$.post("/mycontroller/action", data, function() {});
```

In my controller, I don't want to pollute the existing model coming into the controller. I'd like to be able to add the newMember parameter to the action.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddMember(MemberModel model, bool newMember)
{

}
```

Rather than change MemberModel, I'd like to have the model binder fill newMember, but this doesn't work. How do I get round this problem?

Comment: actually this should work, probably data is not created properly, or you might need to add traditional:true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Rather than change MemberModel

That's exactly what view models are intended for. Your controller actions must receive view models as arguments and pass view models to views.

But anyway if for some reason you don't use view models in your application you could send a JSON request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/mycontroller/action',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        newMember: true,
        model: {
            foo: 'bar'
        }
    }),
    success: function(result) {

    }
});
```

Bear in mind that this works in ASP.NET MVC 3. If you are using an older version you could write a custom JsonValueProvider factory as explained in [this blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx).

Comment: The reason for adding an extra parameter is you might have post actions in different scenarios augmenting the data. The member model might grow over time with each addition. Its hard to see what is really just member model data and what isn't.

Comment: @jaffa, that's view model data, not model data. If you don't use view models your controller action signatures will become way too long and contain lots of parameters. Personally I prefer using view models as it is easier to add properties to a class later rather than modify the signature. But anyway, it's just my point of view.